# excel chart data labels failing to apply to all series

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, formatting, charts

if I have a multiple series chart (pivot chart to be exact, can be line or bar) and I select (from the ribbon)

```
layout   
data labels   
more data label options...
```

then it automatically slaps 'value' based data labels on all series
however, if I then uncheck the 'value' checkbox and select 'labels' instead, it only applies it to one series at random

is there any way to force it to apply to all?

Comment: I believe only the default 'value' is applied to all series, and only when you first invoke it. Subsequent changes muyst be applied to each series in turn.

Comment: this is surely a BUG then?

Comment: No, it's a default setting which probably is appropriate for most cases. Wouldn't it be redundant to label every point in a series with the series name?

Comment: I don't mean with the same series. Ok. So when I perform the actions above, it automatically adds values to every single point on every single series showing the data value in question, what I'm saying is, why, when I decide to show the SERIES name instead of values, it only applies it to a single series and not all of them. What you're left with is a bunch of series, one of which has its series name as the label, the rest of which have values as the label. It looks messy and requires a lot of manual effort to clean it up

Comment: The designers decided to expose the option of what to show only when a single series of data labels (or single data label) is selected.